# Post-Upgrade Scripting for Containers in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I wanted to know if there is any way in kubernetes where i could specify a post upgrade script to be applied on a per container basis once the upgrade of the apps happen

Thanks,

Raks

Comment: Your question is slightly ambiguous; do you want the action to take place after *all* Pods have been upgraded, or do you want the script applied to each Pod as it is brought into service, and having the upgrade script run sequentially is ok?

Comment: @Matthew Daniel: I want to have a per container post upgrade script which has to run as and when individual containers in a POD get upgraded and brought into service. Is there a provision to do this using existing contructs within Kubernetes platform ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [postStart](https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.8/#lifecycle-v1-core) lifecycle hook might do what you want; one will just need to be cautious because it is per Pod creation, which yes, will happen on update, but will also happen if a Pod is terminated for non-upgrade reasons

If you need to keep track of whether a Pod has been upgraded (and thus does not need action if it is just restarted), you can have the Pod add either a label or an annotation to itself using the service account credentials under which it is running.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Will surely try the latter part to see if we can get the clear distinction between an upgrade v/s restart.